# question regarding usage of the idiom “driving me up the wall”

Tags: idioms

english is not my first language, and i’m trying to write a poem.
can you say “this feeling is driving me up the wall” to explain the frustration of having a crush or is it unnatural? i also don’t want to mean it in a sexual way haha

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please read the FAQ. See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: I suggest you do a search on the two strings "_is driving me up the wall_" and "_is driving me crazy_" and decide which of the two, if either, more exactly matches the feeling you want to express.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sw54Pdh_m8

Answer (score 4):

As a native English speaker, I can say that it would be unusual to use the phrase "driving me up the wall" to describe something generally positive (having a crush on someone), but "driving me crazy" might be appropriate.

Typically people say "driving me up the wall" to express frustration at a negative situation, e.g. "My computer keeps crashing and it's driving me up the wall", or "my boss won't stop hassling me today, he's driving me up the wall!"

Comment: Agreed.  Besides, "She Drives Me Crazy" is already the [title of an 80s hit song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sw54Pdh_m8) so there is a clear precedent.